# Add the first line to the beginning of a file to each line with shell

Tags: shell, loops, awk, sed, append

I have a lot of files with the first line of them as an identifier. The subsequent lines are products of the identifier. Here is an example of the file:

```
0G000001:
Product_2221
Product_2222
Product_2122
...
```

I want to put the identifier at the beginning of every line of the file. The final output would be like this:

```
0G000001: Product_2221
0G000001: Product_2222
0G000001: Product:2122
....
```

I want to make a loop for all the files that I have. I've been trying with:

```
for i in $(echo `head -n1 file.$i.txt);
    do
cat - file.$i.txt > file_id.$i.txt;
done
```

But I only duplicate the first line of the file. I know that **sed** can add specific text at the beginning of the file but I can't figure it out to specify that the text is the first line of the file and in a *loop* context.

Comment: sed is for doing `s/old/new/`. You are not doing `s/old/new/` so you should not be considering using sed. For anything else just use awk for a simpler, clearer, more efficient, more robust, more portable, more extensible, etc... solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No explicit loop necessary:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 { close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/\./,"_id&",out); hdr=$0; next }
    { print hdr, $0 > out }
' file.*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1 { prod = $0 } NR>1 { print prod, $0 }' infile
```

Output:

```
0G000001: Product_2221
0G000001: Product_2222
0G000001: Product_2122
```

Comment: `FNR` would work better if there was more than one file.

Comment: @TomFenech: Yes, but that would require more code to handle writing out the results. For that solution, see [Ed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45924191/1331399).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '1h;1d;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file ...
```

Save the first line in the hold space (HS) and then delete it from the pattern space (PS). For every line (other than the first), append the HS to the PS and then swap the lines and replace the newline with a space.

Answer (score 1):

A sed command to do what you want could look like this:

```
$ sed '1{h;d};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' infile
0G000001: Product_2221
0G000001: Product_2222
0G000001: Product_2122
```

This does the following:

```
1 {                       # On the first line
    h                     # Copy the pattern space to the hold space
    d                     # Delete the line, move to next line
}
G                         # Append the hold space to the pattern space
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/   # Swap the lines in the pattern space
```

Some seds might complain about `{h;d}` and require an extra semicolon, `{h;d;}`.

To do this in-place for a file, you can use

```
sed -i '1{h;d};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' infile
```

for GNU sed, or

```
sed -i '' '1{h;d};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' infile
```

for macOS sed. Or, if your sed doesn't support `-i` at all:

```
sed '1{h;d};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' infile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile infile
```

To do it in a loop over all files in a directory:

```
for f in /path/to/dir/*; do
    sed -i '1{h;d};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' "$f"
done
```

or even directly with a glob:

```
sed -i '1{h;d};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' /path/to/dir/*
```

The latter works for sure with GNU sed; not sure about other seds.

Answer (score 1):

***sed*** + ***head*** solution:

```
for f in *.txt; do sed -i '1d; s/^/'"$(head -n1 $f)"' /' "$f"; done
```

---

- `-i` - to modify file in-place
- `1d;` - delete the 1st line
- `$(head -n1 $f)` - extract the 1st line from file (getting identifier)
- `s/^/<identifier> /` - prepend identifier to each line in file